# Is it worth to change only a td instead of the whole table? (html/js)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, performance

I am doing an application that constantly updates a table using websockets. I am updating the table by rewriting it. Which comes to my question should

I rewrite only the td or the whole table?

What's the gain in performance of overwriting only the td versus the extra complexity?

Comment: This sounds like some severely premature optimization.

Comment: if your table is not huge, there is no meaning for optimization

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak or if it does not has constant updates as with realtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing tags is always more expensive than changing the content of a tag because it causes document re-flows. Changing page structure requires that the whole document layout be recalculated.

Comment: This is the kind of smart answer I was loking for. Don't you have a link with more info about this?

Comment: Sure, you'll have to sort it out a bit though: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=jsperf%20reflow

Answer (score 1):

Replacing just one cell's contents will always be faster than replacing the whole table. Either one might cause a document reflow, however. The cell's new contents might be larger or smaller than the old contents.

Your jQuery has an error. `$('td').html('newstuff')` will change the contents of every cell in every table in your document.

Comment: lol I just noticed the mistake but you got the point lol. I thought that the processing might be the same if we consider it searches the whole html to a more specific degree and also that if you change any cell or the table it needs to reflow, which could work like a screen redraw, which would make no large difference in the processing

Comment: If you attach a unique id to the cell you want to change, that id is recorded in an internal lookup table as the html is loaded for the first time. Later on, locating the cell by its id is extremely fast and doesn't require any searching through the html. I just did some timings on `x = $("#myID")` to locate an element with `id="myID"` in the middle of a 1MB document. It takes about a microsecond!

Comment: I just noticed the mention of "comet" in the original question. Comet techniques are often used when there is a constant trickle of small updates arriving from the server. If this is what you are thinking of, then you certainly want to process each update in its own little area of the document. However, if this is a whole new application you are developing, I suggest you get it working first with periodic whole-table updates. You will need to have that capability anyway, in two cases: 1. User loads the page for the first time. 2. Technical problems prevent comet from working for some users.

Answer (score 0):

Change just the column. Is not so complicated. Changing the whole table will be a bad user interface especially on slow networks.

Comment: Exactly, but independently of the "framework" the fewer changes you make the fewer traffic you will occupy. The change should be the more "local" possible!

Comment: Not exactly. Everything depends on your implementation! If you thing that will be more costly if you do it this way then you know more than me about your system but thing that you may need to change the logic of your system. However if you bring lets say 300 rows of data into a table and the other implementation needs only 3 operations each time per column then it's better to use the second approach. In general if you look at it from 2000 feet above the REST approach is always better than other older approaches...

Comment: One more comment is that it depends also on what you talking about. If for example you speak strictly for JQuery then the things change... I was talking about the communication between the client and server. On the client you shouldn't really care so much because the execution happens on the clients machine. It's more important to have the server up and running than care about 10 milisecond delay on the clients machine. Later you can refactor the code....